# Trying to use fitText.js

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to get `fittext.js` working, but I am getting no results, here is a JsFiddle that I am working on: [Demo working](http://jsfiddle.net/sLXZs/).

### Html

```
<div id="austin">
    <div id="headLine">
        <h1>Austin Kitson</h1>
        <h2>Marketing & Sales</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Javascript (changed selector to what i actually had)

```
<script>
   jQuery("#headLine h1").fitText();
</script>
```

### CSS

```
html{
    font-size: 62.5%; 
}
#austin {
    width: 20em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
#headLine {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    left: 57%; 
}
#headLine h1 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I dont see any "responsive_headline" ID in your HTML.

Comment: @highwingers oops, I wrote the wrong one in the post and on js fiddle, i edited the top and put in what I actually have, still not seeing fittext work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add a width to the #headline

```
#headLine {
    position: absolute;
    **width:100%;**
    top: 28%;
    left: 57%; 
}
```